# IF time range return "DAY AM", "DAY PM", "NIGHT"

Tags: time, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Basic query but I keep getting `#ERROR!`. I want to auto generate "DAY AM", "DAY PM", "NIGHT", from the time. The failed formula I wrote is:

```
=IF(AND(D47>6,D47<18),”Day”,IF(AND(D47>18,D47<24),”NIGHT”,IF(AND(D47>0,D47<6),”NGHT”)))
```

In column D is the time, in 24 hr format e.g. `13:45` or `00:40`. For the sake of this formula I am defining "day" as between 06:00 – 17:59. From 18:00 – 00:00 and 0:00 – 05:59 is "night".

Comment: Hi pnuts, sorry I should have given an example. In column D is the time, in 24 hr format e.g. 13:45 or 00:40

For the sake of this formula I am defining "day" as between 06:00 – 17:59. From 18:00 – 00:00 and 0:00 – 05:59 is "night".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your formula, divide all hour numbers by `24`. (`06:00` is displayed but the underlying value is actually `0.25` (ie a quarter of a day) ).

Don't use smart quotes (`“`) where straight ones (`"`) are required (ie throughout) ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48477463/1505120)).

Don't span noon if you want AM distinct from PM (ie break up `(D47>6,D47<18)` into something like `(D47>6,D47<12)` and `(D47>12,D47<18)`).

Decide what is to happen at the cusps. That is, for example, what happens when D47 is neither greater than `06:00` nor less than `06:00` (may want some equal signs alongside some angle brackets).

You are probably missing an `I` from the last word in your formula.

An `OR` in the right place might simplify your formula.

Answer (score 1):

Try using straight quotes `"` instead of `“`

Answer (score 0):

```
=let(inttime, int(substitute(mid(d47,1,5),":","")),
    if(inttime<559, "night",
        if(inttime<1759, "day",
            "night"
        )
    ) 
)
```

I find it easier to keep track of my nested function calls and parentheses by using indentation. This is kind of like a case statement or if-elseif-else-endif block.

I use the let() function to define a variable I call inttime. If d47 holds the datetime in exactly the format you provided, then mid() finds where the time is within that larger string, substitute() strips the colon out of it, then int() converts that into an integer, which I store to the variable inttime.

From there I start at midnight (0) and deal with every time period you define, earliest first. I can use that variable I defined earlier, instead of having to run functions to find the time again for every comparison. That "night" on its own line is in the else() section - what the time label defaults to if none of the other conditions are met.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**